# Javascript array filter seems to work, but doesn't print to screen

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

1. 4 years are added to the array (2001, 1999, 2000 and 2002)
2. The array is printed to screen, showing the same 4 years
3. The maximum year is calculated as 2002
4. The year 2002 is deleted from the array
5. The array is printed to screen, but still showing 4 years
6. Nevertheless, the maximum year is calculated as 2001, indicating that 2002 was actually deleted

What's going on?

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');

function handleYears() {
    let years = [];
    let addYear = function(newYear) {
        years.push(newYear);
    }
    let deleteYear = function(yearToDelete) {
        years = years.filter(item => item !== yearToDelete)
    }
    let calculateMaxYear = function() {
        return Math.max(...years);
    }

    return {
        years: years,
        addYear: addYear,
        deleteYear: deleteYear,
        calculateMaxYear: calculateMaxYear
    }
}

let newHandleYears = handleYears();

newHandleYears.addYear(2001);
newHandleYears.addYear(1999);
newHandleYears.addYear(2000);
newHandleYears.addYear(2002);

output.innerHTML += `<p>Years: ${newHandleYears.years}</p>`;
output.innerHTML += `<p>Maximum year: ${newHandleYears.calculateMaxYear()}</p>`;
output.innerHTML += `<p>Delete item "${newHandleYears.years[newHandleYears.years.length - 1]}" from "years" array.</p>`;

newHandleYears.deleteYear(2002);

output.innerHTML += `<p>Years: ${newHandleYears.years}</p>`;
output.innerHTML += `<p>Maximum year: ${newHandleYears.calculateMaxYear()}</p>`;
```

```css
body {padding: 0.5rem 1rem;}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `this` keyword because you are reassigning value and you don't have to do it in push since its calling same reference and pushing to it.

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');

function handleYears() {
    let years = [];
    let addYear = function(newYear) {
        years.push(newYear);
    }
    let deleteYear = function(yearToDelete) {
        this.years = years.filter(item => item !== yearToDelete)
    }
    let calculateMaxYear = function() {
        return Math.max(...this.years);
    }

    return {
        years: years,
        addYear: addYear,
        deleteYear: deleteYear,
        calculateMaxYear: calculateMaxYear
    }
}

let newHandleYears = handleYears();

newHandleYears.addYear(2001);
newHandleYears.addYear(1999);
newHandleYears.addYear(2000);
newHandleYears.addYear(2002);

output.innerHTML += `<p>Years: ${newHandleYears.years}</p>`;
output.innerHTML += `<p>Maximum year: ${newHandleYears.calculateMaxYear()}</p>`;
output.innerHTML += `<p>Delete item "${newHandleYears.years[newHandleYears.years.length - 1]}" from "years" array.</p>`;

newHandleYears.deleteYear(2002);

output.innerHTML += `<p>Years: ${newHandleYears.years}</p>`;
output.innerHTML += `<p>Maximum year: ${newHandleYears.calculateMaxYear()}</p>`;
```

```css
body {padding: 0.5rem 1rem;}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, miyav. I don't understand why this works. The add and delete functions seem to work, but the array, as it is displayed just hasn't refreshed. How does the `this` keyword remedy this? I'm trying to reconcile your solution with Igor's (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71885035/2700249), which instead adds an extra getter function to update newHandleYears.

Answer (score 1):

After deleting a year, the `newHandleYears` object is not initialised with the new `years` value, it holds the old one. You can make another getter for `years` to get the updated value:

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');

function handleYears() {
    let years = [];
    let addYear = (newYear) => {
        years.push(newYear);
    }
    let deleteYear = (yearToDelete) => {
        years = years.filter(item => item !== yearToDelete)
    }
    let calculateMaxYear = () => {
        return Math.max(...years);
    }
    let getYears = () => {
        return years
    }

    return {
        getYears: getYears,
        addYear: addYear,
        deleteYear: deleteYear,
        calculateMaxYear: calculateMaxYear
    }
}

let newHandleYears = handleYears();

newHandleYears.addYear(2001);
newHandleYears.addYear(1999);
newHandleYears.addYear(2000);
newHandleYears.addYear(2002);

output.innerHTML += `<p>Years: ${newHandleYears.getYears()}</p>`;
output.innerHTML += `<p>Maximum year: ${newHandleYears.calculateMaxYear()}</p>`;
output.innerHTML += `<p>Delete item "${newHandleYears.getYears()[newHandleYears.getYears().length - 1]}" from "years" array.</p>`;

newHandleYears.deleteYear(2002);

output.innerHTML += `<p>Years: ${newHandleYears.getYears()}</p>`;
output.innerHTML += `<p>Maximum year: ${newHandleYears.calculateMaxYear()}</p>`;
```

```css
body {padding: 0.5rem 1rem;}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Igor. This makes sense to me. However, I'm trying to understand why both your solution and miyav's (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71884892/2700249) achieve the same result.

Comment: Miyav's solution works because when using `this` you are referencing the object `newHandleYears` and it updates the value of already created object. Subsequently any manipulation of `years` property of the created object should be done through `this`. When you don't use `this` you are referencing the `years` variable in the local scope of `handleYears` function. You cannot access it directly from outside function scope, that's why you have to use a getter.

Comment: Thanks, Igor. I prefer the getter function for consistency. BTW, I have posted a further issue after I tried to introduce a click event (https://stackoverflow.com/q/71885911/2700249).