# Closure with methods works until called from a click event

Tags: javascript, html

I am expanding [this working code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71885035/2700249) to supply the data via a select menu and run it via a click event. However, what was returned as text values, now returns weird stuff like:

```
{
  /**id:1**/
  "isTrusted": true,
  "initMouseEvent": function initMouseEvent() {
    [native code]
  },
...
```

The change from the aforementioned working code is that the call to the closure methods is now within a click event listener. Any idea what is happening here?

```js
// 

const addButton = document.getElementById('addYear');
const deleteButton = document.getElementById('deleteYear');
const yearSelect = document.getElementById('yearSelect');
let selectedYear = yearSelect.options[yearSelect.selectedIndex].value;
const output = document.getElementById('output');
                           
// 
                           
let newHandleYears = handleYears();

// 

addButton.addEventListener("click", function(selectedYear) {
    newHandleYears.addYear(selectedYear);
    console.log(selectedYear);
    output.innerHTML += `<p>Years: ${newHandleYears.getYears()}</p>`;
    output.innerHTML += `<p>Maximum year: ${newHandleYears.calculateMaxYear()}</p>`;
});

deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    output.innerHTML += `<p>Delete item "${newHandleYears.years[newHandleYears.years.length - 1]}" from "years" array.</p>`;
    newHandleYears.deleteYear(2002); // WIP
    output.innerHTML += `<p>Years: ${newHandleYears.getYears()}</p>`;
    output.innerHTML += `<p>Maximum year: ${newHandleYears.calculateMaxYear()}</p>`;
});
                           
// 

function handleYears() {
    let years = [];
    let addYear = (newYear) => {
        years.push(newYear);
    }
    let deleteYear = (yearToDelete) => {
        years = years.filter(item => item !== yearToDelete)
    }
    let calculateMaxYear = () => {
        return Math.max(...years);
    }
    let getYears = () => {
        return years
    }

    return {
        getYears: getYears,
        addYear: addYear,
        deleteYear: deleteYear,
        calculateMaxYear: calculateMaxYear
    }
}
```

```css
body {padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;}

#output {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <p>
        <label for="yearSelect">Year</label>
        <select id="yearSelect">
            <option value="">Select one...</option>
            <option value="1948">1948</option>
            <option value="1949">1949</option>
            <option value="1950">1950</option>
            <option value="1951">1951</option>
            <option value="1952">1952</option>
            <option value="1953">1953</option>
            <option value="1954">1954</option>
            <option value="1955">1955</option>
            <option value="1956">1956</option>
            <option value="1957">1957</option>
            <option value="1958">1958</option>
            <option value="1959">1959</option>
            <option value="1960">1960</option>
            <option value="1961">1961</option>
            <option value="1962">1962</option>
            <option value="1963">1963</option>
            <option value="1964">1964</option>
            <option value="1965">1965</option>
            <option value="1966">1966</option>
            <option value="1967">1967</option>
            <option value="1968">1968</option>
            <option value="1969">1969</option>
            <option value="1970">1970</option>
            <option value="1971">1971</option>
            <option value="1972">1972</option>
            <option value="1973">1973</option>
            <option value="1974">1974</option>
            <option value="1975">1975</option>
            <option value="1976">1976</option>
            <option value="1977">1977</option>
            <option value="1978">1978</option>
            <option value="1979">1979</option>
            <option value="1980">1980</option>
            <option value="1981">1981</option>
            <option value="1982">1982</option>
            <option value="1983">1983</option>
            <option value="1984">1984</option>
            <option value="1985">1985</option>
            <option value="1986">1986</option>
            <option value="1987">1987</option>
            <option value="1988">1988</option>
            <option value="1989">1989</option>
            <option value="1990">1990</option>
            <option value="1991">1991</option>
            <option value="1992">1992</option>
            <option value="1993">1993</option>
            <option value="1994">1994</option>
            <option value="1995">1995</option>
            <option value="1996">1996</option>
            <option value="1997">1997</option>
            <option value="1998">1998</option>
            <option value="1999">1999</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="2001">2001</option>
            <option value="2002">2002</option>
            <option value="2003">2003</option>
            <option value="2004">2004</option>
            <option value="2005">2005</option>
            <option value="2006">2006</option>
            <option value="2007">2007</option>
            <option value="2008">2008</option>
            <option value="2009">2009</option>
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
            <option value="2020">2020</option>
            <option value="2021">2021</option>
            <option value="2022">2022</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" id="addYear" value="Add">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" id="deleteYear" value="Delete">
    </p>
</form>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Which method is returning that?

Comment: `selectedYear` is the argument to an event handler function you've provided, so it will be the native [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object corresponding to the event that's happening - which contains all that stuff. The other answer you linked to does not seem really related at all so it's hard to compare, but that's why you get all that stuff logged. Is this actually a problem?

Comment: `newHandleYears.addYear(selectedYear)` doesn't seem right. Shouldn't you be adding the value from the dropdown? If you expected that to use the global variable, it won't because it's the parameter to the event listener. But even if you get rid of the parameter, it contains the initial value of the dropdown, not the current value.

Comment: Thanks, @RobinZigmond. I was expecting `selectedYear` to be the value of the selected select option because it is defined as `yearSelect.options[yearSelect.selectedIndex].value` and does console.log the year. The other answer uses exactly the same function and methods, but introduces a click event and DOM elements. I thought I was passing the year into the click function to be used by the add function. I guess I don't fully understand event listeners.

Comment: Hi @Barmar. I thought that `selectedYear` was the selected value of the dropdown: `const yearSelect = document.getElementById('yearSelect');
let selectedYear = yearSelect.options[yearSelect.selectedIndex].value;`

Comment: You set that variable when the page first loads. It doesn't update automatically when they change the dropdown.

Comment: Yes, of course. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedYear` should be a local variable inside the listener function, not a parameter to the function. The function parameter is the event, it shadows the global variable. And the global variable only has the value of the dropdown from when the page first loaded, not the value after they click the button.

```js
// 

const addButton = document.getElementById('addYear');
const deleteButton = document.getElementById('deleteYear');
const yearSelect = document.getElementById('yearSelect');
const output = document.getElementById('output');

// 

let newHandleYears = handleYears();

// 

addButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let selectedYear = yearSelect.value;
  newHandleYears.addYear(selectedYear);
  console.log(selectedYear);
  output.innerHTML += `<p>Years: ${newHandleYears.getYears()}</p>`;
  output.innerHTML += `<p>Maximum year: ${newHandleYears.calculateMaxYear()}</p>`;
});

deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  output.innerHTML += `<p>Delete item "${newHandleYears.years[newHandleYears.years.length - 1]}" from "years" array.</p>`;
  newHandleYears.deleteYear(2002); // WIP
  output.innerHTML += `<p>Years: ${newHandleYears.getYears()}</p>`;
  output.innerHTML += `<p>Maximum year: ${newHandleYears.calculateMaxYear()}</p>`;
});

// 

function handleYears() {
  let years = [];
  let addYear = (newYear) => {
    years.push(newYear);
  }
  let deleteYear = (yearToDelete) => {
    years = years.filter(item => item !== yearToDelete)
  }
  let calculateMaxYear = () => {
    return Math.max(...years);
  }
  let getYears = () => {
    return years
  }

  return {
    getYears: getYears,
    addYear: addYear,
    deleteYear: deleteYear,
    calculateMaxYear: calculateMaxYear
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}

#output {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="yearSelect">Year</label>
    <select id="yearSelect">
      <option value="">Select one...</option>
      <option value="1948">1948</option>
      <option value="1949">1949</option>
      <option value="1950">1950</option>
      <option value="1951">1951</option>
      <option value="1952">1952</option>
      <option value="1953">1953</option>
      <option value="1954">1954</option>
      <option value="1955">1955</option>
      <option value="1956">1956</option>
      <option value="1957">1957</option>
      <option value="1958">1958</option>
      <option value="1959">1959</option>
      <option value="1960">1960</option>
      <option value="1961">1961</option>
      <option value="1962">1962</option>
      <option value="1963">1963</option>
      <option value="1964">1964</option>
      <option value="1965">1965</option>
      <option value="1966">1966</option>
      <option value="1967">1967</option>
      <option value="1968">1968</option>
      <option value="1969">1969</option>
      <option value="1970">1970</option>
      <option value="1971">1971</option>
      <option value="1972">1972</option>
      <option value="1973">1973</option>
      <option value="1974">1974</option>
      <option value="1975">1975</option>
      <option value="1976">1976</option>
      <option value="1977">1977</option>
      <option value="1978">1978</option>
      <option value="1979">1979</option>
      <option value="1980">1980</option>
      <option value="1981">1981</option>
      <option value="1982">1982</option>
      <option value="1983">1983</option>
      <option value="1984">1984</option>
      <option value="1985">1985</option>
      <option value="1986">1986</option>
      <option value="1987">1987</option>
      <option value="1988">1988</option>
      <option value="1989">1989</option>
      <option value="1990">1990</option>
      <option value="1991">1991</option>
      <option value="1992">1992</option>
      <option value="1993">1993</option>
      <option value="1994">1994</option>
      <option value="1995">1995</option>
      <option value="1996">1996</option>
      <option value="1997">1997</option>
      <option value="1998">1998</option>
      <option value="1999">1999</option>
      <option value="2000">2000</option>
      <option value="2001">2001</option>
      <option value="2002">2002</option>
      <option value="2003">2003</option>
      <option value="2004">2004</option>
      <option value="2005">2005</option>
      <option value="2006">2006</option>
      <option value="2007">2007</option>
      <option value="2008">2008</option>
      <option value="2009">2009</option>
      <option value="2010">2010</option>
      <option value="2011">2011</option>
      <option value="2012">2012</option>
      <option value="2013">2013</option>
      <option value="2014">2014</option>
      <option value="2015">2015</option>
      <option value="2016">2016</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
      <option value="2018">2018</option>
      <option value="2019">2019</option>
      <option value="2020">2020</option>
      <option value="2021">2021</option>
      <option value="2022">2022</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" id="addYear" value="Add">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" id="deleteYear" value="Delete">
  </p>
</form>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are making things unnecessarily complicated for yourself. The following script will probably do exactly what you intended. The only global constant created is `D`, an object containing DOM references and the property `years` holding the selected years as an array.

```js
const D=Object.fromEntries(['myForm','yearSelect','output'].map(n=>[n,document.getElementById(n)]));
D.years=[];D.n=75;D.start=new Date().getFullYear()-D.n+1;
D.yearSelect.innerHTML+=[...Array(D.n)].map((_,i)=>`<option>${i+D.start}</option>`).join("");            

D.myForm.onclick=function(ev){
 const y=D.yearSelect.value;
 if(ev.target.type==="button"){
  switch (ev.target.id){
   case "addYear":
    if(y) D.years.push(y);
    break;
   case "deleteFirstYear":
    D.years.shift();
    break;
   case "deleteSelectedYear":
    let pos=D.years.indexOf(y);
    if(pos>-1) D.years.splice(pos,1);
    break;
   default: // deletelatestYear
    D.years.pop();
  }
  D.output.innerHTML = D.years.length?`<p>Years: ${D.years.join(", ")}</p>
  <p>Maximum year: ${Math.max(...D.years)}</p>`:"";
 }
}
```

```css
body {padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;}

#output {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <p>
        <label for="yearSelect">Year</label>
        <select id="yearSelect">
            <option value="">Select one...</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p><input type="button" id="deleteFirstYear" value="Delete first"></p>
    <p><input type="button" id="addYear" value="Add"></p>
    <p><input type="button" id="deleteSelectedYear" value="Delete selected"></p>
    <p><input type="button" id="deleteLatestYear" value="Delete latest"></p>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

In the above script there is only one click handler function, bound to the form element. Depending on which button is clicked, different parts of the `switch` expression are performed. I added another button simply to demonstrate how easy it is to add functionality in this concept.

Comment: Thanks, @Carsten. You may be right. I am coming extremely late to the Closure party. So, this is good practice for me. Your code is certainly more efficient, but it will take me a while to understand it fully. It hurts my brain just looking at the first couple of lines ;)